# Setting option for speech to text on Huawei mobile?

Tags: huawei, voice-recognition

As we know, Android comes with an in-built feature, speech to text. But I failed to find any setting options for speech to text on my Huawei Mate 9 phone.

Does my mobile use online speech recognition service offered by Google or a service by Huawei?
Does my mobile support offline speech recognition? How many languages have been supported? ...

Thank you in advance.